# How to avoid htmlentities() function in ckeditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

Hi i am using ckeditor plugin to beautify the text given by the user.It was working properly but now i try to increase security to my website so that i used htmlentities() function in all places where echo is used.

The problem is while displaying a text output from ckeditor are shown as html tags in my website because of the effect of htmlentities() i used.This is the output i am getting in my website,

```
<p><strong><span style="color:#008080">Superhero</span></strong></p>
```

So the look of website is damaged.I want to show the ckeditor text as it is.But htmlentities()
must have to be used.

I searched stack overflow and found many issues related to this.So i used the following solution in my ckeditor/config.js page as below,

```
config.entities  = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
```

But its not working in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I am aware there is no in-built way in php to distinguish between malicious injected script tags and normal html tags.

This leads to problem where you want to block malicious script, but not valid html tags.

When I have to accept user input and display again which may contain html tags, instead of using `htmlentities` I use [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). There is another one I am aware of is [safeHtml](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html).

However, there might be better solutions then this and I am also interested in knowing as well. Unfortunately haven't came across one.